# Permission denied for .pid file in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to start celery beat in elastic beanstalk like this:

```
celery beat -A project --loglevel=INFO --pidfile=/var/log/celerybeat.pid
```

No matter what folder I enter I keep getting permission denied error.

Some threads suggest that I use root permissions but I think it is bad.

Any other way to do this?